# How Jsoup could clean XSS javascripts and maintain some HTML tags?

Tags: html, jsoup, xss, client-side-attacks

I want to clean some HTML Strings in my application in Java from XSS attacks using Jsoup.

But i want to have also `<a>` and `<img>` tags.

Is it this possible with this library?

Answer (score 1):

I found this link from the official website with the right answer to my question.

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Using Whitelist, I could define the next:

```
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basicWithImages());
```